# Meteor FS link leads to 404 Error

Tags: reactjs, meteor, http-status-code-404

I am currently developing a Meteor React app, which is using the ostrio:files package to store audio files in a collection named Files. In another (regular mongo) collection, I am using the following code in the transform function to "join" the document with the link to the audio file:

```
transform: function(doc){  
    let curAudio = doc.audio;
    let audioFile = Files.collection.findOne({_id: curAudio.file_id});
    if(audioFile){
        curAudio.audioLink = Files.link(audioFile);
        curAudio.audioLength = audioFile.meta.length;
        curAudio.audioSize = audioFile.size;
        doc.audio = curAudio;
    }
    return doc;
}
```

This seems to work just fine, as the resulting audio.audioLink is something like

```
 http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/files/8Q7WwEXyJSkNWwFQa/original/8Q7WwEXyJSkNWwFQa.m4a
```

But when I try to do something like this

```
<audio controls preload="none" style={{width: "480px"}}>
    <source src={track.audioLink} type="audio/mp4"/>
    <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.</p>
</audio>
```

To be able to play the file, everything works until I click the play button of the HTML5 player. Then, chrome outputs to the console, that the server returned 404 when the file was supposed to be loaded. I tested putting the link into the adress bar, here the server response is just

```
File Not Found :(
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
My local Ubuntu installation was apparently configured to store uploaded files in /tmp, which didn't caus problems until I restarted the system or cleared my temporary files otherwise. Having the server recreate the DB fixed the problem.